# Non-normal sampling for card shuffling

Tags: r, probability-distribution

I have a script that uses `sample()` to shuffle a pack of cards into four hands - Shown below.

This script produces normally distributed hand splits. That is the distributions of the 13 cards in a suit across the four hands will be "4432" 21.6% of the time, "5442" 15.5% of the time, ... - See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge_probabilities#Hand%20pattern%20probabilities.

Is there a way to make `sample()` give non-normal distributions, e.g. Flatten the profile, so that  the distributions across the hands deviate from the expected probabilities? `sample()` can take a weighting parameter, but can't see how to use this to achieve my goals.  Alternatively, is there another sampling function that could provide this?

Thank you,

TC

```
# Set up
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

# Build pack
pack <- expand.grid(rank = c("A", 2:9, "T", "J", "Q", "K"), suit = c("S", "H", "D", "C")) %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "minimal") %>%
  mutate(card = paste(suit, rank, sep = "-"))

# Divide cards into hands
for (i in 1:4) {
  temp <- sample(pack$card, 13, replace = FALSE) %>%
    as_tibble(.name_repair = "minimal") %>%
    separate(value, sep = "-", into = c("suit", "rank")) %>%
    mutate(
      suit = factor(suit, levels = c("S", "H", "D", "C")),
      rank = factor(rank, levels = c("A", "K", "Q", "J", "T", 9:2, " "))
    ) %>%
    arrange(suit, rank) %>%
    unite("card", sep = "-")

  assign(glue::glue("hand{i}"), temp)
  
  pack <- pack %>%
    filter(!card %in% unname(unlist(temp)))
}

# Reassemble pack
pack <- hand1 %>% 
  cbind(hand2) %>%
  cbind(hand3) %>%
  cbind(hand4) %>% 
  rename(N = 1, E = 2, S = 3, W = 4)
```

Comment: `sample` uses a uniform distribution not a normal.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. As already pointed out, sample uses a uniform sampling technique because it's designed to work with discrete values. Sampling from a normal distribution really only makes sense for continuous values. What exactly is the probability distribution you are trying to achieve? If you don't know the distribution you want, then maybe you should seek statistical help at [stats.se] first since this might not be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would try to make your script more like reality. Currently you are starting with a sorted deck, and then using `sample` to draw cards from random positions in the deck. Instead, I would suggest developing a `shuffle` function that reorders the deck, perhaps "cuts" the deck, and then draw cards for each hand off the top of the deck. You could then experiment with different `shuffle` algorithms that perturb the deck different amounts.

Comment: For example, `deck[rank(1:52 + runif(52, min  = -5, max = 12))), ]` would be a weird shuffle method. Try longtailed distributions, `rcauchy`, `rt`, ...

Comment: @GregorThomas and MrFlick Thank you.  Your comments helped me clarify my question.  It boils down to, "Can I change the sampling method that sample() uses,  allowing manipulation of the parameters (e.g. kurtosis, skewness) or directly applying a different distribution, e.g. bimodal, Cauchy?". I'll investigate your thoughts further.

Comment: The control you have over `sample` is documented on the help page - you can set the weights. It's not clear to me what kurtosis or skewness would mean in relation to sampling discrete items from a finite set, with or without replacement---which is what `sample` does. But you can certainly come up with other methods to randomize the order of items that rely on different distributions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the process of creating the deck, shuffling, and dealing as follows:

```
# Create the deck
Suit <- c("S", "H", "D", "C")
Rank <- c("A", 2:9, "T", "J", "Q", "K")
Deck <- data.frame(Rank=rep(Rank, 4), Suit=rep(Suit, each=13))

# Shuffle and deal
Shuffle <- Deck[sample(nrow(Deck)), ]  # Shuffle the deck
Hand <- factor(rep(c("N", "E", "S", "W"), 13), levels=c("N", "E", "S", "W"))
Deal <- data.frame(Hand, Shuffle)
```

Now deal is a data frame showing the cards in each hand. To get the distribution of cards by suit:

```
xtabs(~Suit+Hand, Even)
#     Hand
# Suit N E S W
#    C 3 3 3 4
#    D 3 3 4 3
#    H 3 4 3 3
#    S 4 3 3 3
```

To get the hands:

```
split(Deal, Deal$Hand)
# $N
#    Hand Rank Suit
# 12    N    Q    S
# 2     N    2    S
# 37    N    J    D
# 49    N    T    C
# 43    N    4    C
# 17    N    4    H
# 33    N    7    D
# 26    N    K    H
# 13    N    K    S
# 44    N    5    C
# 18    N    5    H
# 46    N    7    C
# 11    N    J    S
.  .  .  .  .
```

Since you mention Hand Pattern Probabilities, it may be helpful to show how you can generate them empirically:

```
HPP <- function() {
    Shuffle <- Deck[sample(nrow(Deck)), ]  # Shuffle the deck
    Hand <- factor(rep(c("N", "E", "S", "W"), 13), levels=c("N", "E", "S", "W"))
    Deal <- data.frame(Hand, Shuffle)
    tbl <- xtabs(~Suit+Hand, Deal)
    return(unname(apply(tbl, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE), collapse="-"))))
}

X <- replicate(1000, HPP())
HP <- prop.table(sort(table(X), decreasing=TRUE))
as.matrix(HP)
#            [,1]
# 4-4-3-2 0.22200
# 5-3-3-2 0.14925
# 5-4-3-1 0.12075
# 4-3-3-3 0.11225
# 5-4-2-2 0.10775
# 6-3-2-2 0.05175
# 6-4-2-1 0.04850
#  .  .  .  .
```

To get more "even" distributions of cards by suit, you have to break the random distribution of the shuffle, for example we can shuffle the rank values in the deck but preserve the order of the suits:

```
Even <- Deck
Even$Rank <- c(replicate(4, sample(Rank)))
Even <- data.frame(Hand, Even)
```

Now the card values will differ, but the distribution by suit will always be the same.

Comment: Thank you - Good answer. The more efficient hand dealing is useful: Speed is always important.  Though, you're still using an unmodified Sample(), and so the distribution will be normal, even with subsequent resampling.  I'm looking for a "non-normal" distribution. I'll go through your answer, and post a simpler question, if a solution eludes me - (e.g. When flipping a pair of coins many times, getting "HT"/"TH" is twice as likely as both "HH" or "TT".  Can I bias the coins, for example so that all 3 were equally likely or "HH" occurred 50% of the time?)

Comment: Maybe you can scale this approach up: `flip2 <- c("HH", "HT", "TH", "TT")`; `table(sample(flip2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1/3, 1/6, 1/6, 1/3)))`, but with 4 suits and 13 draws it will be more complicated.

Comment: On second thought, it would be simpler and faster to draw hands randomly and then remove hands that do not meet your criteria. The Wikipedia page you cited provides the most common suit distributions. Just draw 100 hands and remove the ones that do not meet your requirements. This might make sense if some hands provide differential advantages to players and you want the game to emphasis skill over luck.

Comment: "Deal -> Check for characteristics -> Keep or Redeal" is a good idea.  I went that route, but as the probabilities of getting a specific layout diminishes, it takes ever longer to generate the required hands.  So, I hoped, by starting with a strange distribution, then it should be quicker to find the required layouts.  Thank you for your help.